# Can the games in Chernev's Logical Chess Move by Move be played in any order?

Tags: books

In Chernev's Logical Chess Move by Move, can the chapters and games be absorbed in any order, or are they intended to be played through in order?

Comment: really great book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to know something about the structure of the book. There are just 3 chapters in which 33 games are fully annotated. That is every move, even ones like 1. e4 or 1. d4, is annotated with comments, sometimes copious and often anodyne.

These are the chapters:

1. The King-Side Attack (16 games)
2. The Queen's Pawn Opening (7 games)
3. The Chess Master Explains His Ideas (10 games)

It's worth noting that in chapter 3 the "Chess Master" explaining "his" ideas is not the player playing the game. It is Chernev.

With every move "fully" annotated, sometimes in painful detail, there is no need to read / absorb any one game before any other.

For instance, the first game (game 24 in the book) in chapter 3 starts with over half a page of annotation for the first move of the game, 1. d4. I was tempted to reproduce that in full, but life is too short and I would likely fall asleep half way through. So, here is just the last paragraph:

> White's move of the Queen Pawn begins the process of getting *all* the pieces into play as quickly as possible. Two of them are now free to make their debut, while the Pawn which released them occupies the center of the stage.

I'm sure those cliched (if true) sentiments have been expressed several (if not many) times previously in this book. Note that this paragraph is preceded by two much longer paragraphs on the general idea of queen's pawn openings despite the fact that the previous chapter was all about - queen's pawn openings.

No, it really doesn't make any difference what order you tackle these chapters and games.